# Java Text Preprocessing and Clean-Up

Tags: text-processing, java

Could you please recomend me java libraries for text prerprocessing and clean up? The lib should perform such tasks:

- convert all verbs to infinitive
- convert all nouns to singular form
- remove useless (for the sense of a text) words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting words to canonical forms (verbs to infinitives and nouns to singular, for example) is called *[lemmatization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation)*. One Java-based lemmatizer is [Standford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml).

For "useless words" you probably want "stop words" - there's no standard list, but there's a lot floating around the Internet which function in more or less the same way with the only difference being how many words they include (typically between 100 and 1000). I've known people to use [this list](http://www.lextek.com/manuals/onix/stopwords1.html) before. When removing stop words, remember to ignore case when looking for matches.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this does everything you need, but check out mrsqg.

http://code.google.com/p/mrsqg/

Comment: What does this have to do with the question at all?